# React hook Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

When I clicked `add to cart` button for a individual product then show me error like this:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This  could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

I have tried like this:
here is my `cartScreen.js` code

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addToCart } from "../action/cartAction";

const CartScreen = (props) => {
  const productId = props.match.params.id;
  const qty = props.location.search
    ? Number(props.location.search.split("=")[1])
    : 1;
  const disptach = useDispatch;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      disptach(addToCart(productId, qty));
    }
  }, [disptach, productId, qty]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Cart Screen</h2>
      <p>
        Add to Cart : ProductId: {productId} Qty: {qty}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartScreen;
```

But When I have comment out `useEffect` hook then does not show me any error:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      disptach(addToCart(productId, qty));
    }
  }, [disptach, productId, qty]);
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: No, I have use, `redux` for state management

Comment: change   const disptach = useDispatch;   into   const disptach = useDispatch()

Comment: bad typeError <:  Thank you bro.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this from:

```
  const disptach = useDispatch;
```

to:

```
  const disptach = useDispatch(); // useDispatch() is a hook
```

**Let me know if it works, good Luck**

Comment: Yes, It was fixed